# Python не добавляется строка в базу данных

Tags: python, python-3.5

При выполнении программы не добавляется строка в базу данных

```
connection=pymysql.connect(
    host='192.168.***.***',
    user='*******',
    password='****',
    database='***',
    charset='utf8mb4',
    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
)
mycursor=connection.cursor()
logfile=open('logfile','w')
myout=subprocess.Popen(["lastb"],
                       stdout=logfile)
stdout=myout.communicate()
logfile.close()
with open('logfile','r') as file:
    con=file.readlines()
    str1=con[0]
    str2=con[1]
    str=str1.split(":")
    str3=str2.split(":")
    if (str[2]==str3[2]):
       s+=1
       s2=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
       ni.ifaddresses('ens33')
       s3 = ni.ifaddresses('ens33')[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']
       subprocess.call("usermod -L user1",shell=True)
       from tkinter import messagebox
       messagebox.showinfo("Ошибка", "Ваш аккаунт заблокирован")
       # subprocess.call("loginctl terminate-session $XDG_SESSION_ID", shell=True)
       mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO FAKT VALUES('{}','{}','{}','НСД в ОС')".format(s,s3,s2))
       connection.close()
```

результатом программы является: Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

После выполнения SQL необходимо добавить commit()

```
connection.commit()
```